# MessageBrokerServlet initialization problems- Push data from java to Flex application

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds

**Hi All**,

I am working on a server push from Java to Flex. But some how the MessageBrokerServlet is not getting initialized, seems like it is calling a method from:

```
flex.messaging.config.LoginCommandSettings.setMatch()
```

Eventually I found out that this method indeed does not exist in that class (**LoginCommandSettings**). I there something else that is going wrong ?

**This is what the tomcat log says:**

```
2012-01-24 14:04:57 StandardContext[/mywebapp]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: flex.messaging.config.LoginCommandSettings.setMatch(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at flex.messaging.config.ServerConfigurationParser.securitySection(ServerConfigurationParser.java:172)
at flex.messaging.config.ServerConfigurationParser.parseTopLevelConfig(ServerConfigurationParser.java:53)
at flex.messaging.config.AbstractConfigurationParser.parse(AbstractConfigurationParser.java:68)
at flex.messaging.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:77)
at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1029)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

2012-01-24 14:04:57 StandardWrapperValve[MessageBrokerServlet]: Allocate exception for servlet MessageBrokerServlet
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet MessageBrokerServlet threw exception
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1071)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
—– Root Cause —–
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: flex.messaging.config.LoginCommandSettings.setMatch(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at flex.messaging.config.ServerConfigurationParser.securitySection(ServerConfigurationParser.java:172)
at flex.messaging.config.ServerConfigurationParser.parseTopLevelConfig(ServerConfigurationParser.java:53)
at flex.messaging.config.AbstractConfigurationParser.parse(AbstractConfigurationParser.java:68)
at flex.messaging.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:77)
at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1029)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am new to flex programming and using **tomcat server- jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28** for deploying the web-app. I have made all the changes to **messaging-config.xml**, **services-config.xml** and written a Java class with a thread to keep pushing the data.

I have used 2 libraries in my java code:

1. blazeds-common-3.0
2. flex-messaging

I am stuck with this since last 2 days...
So any help in this context would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks in Advance !!

-Adwait

This is my messaging-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="message-service" 
    class="flex.messaging.services.MessageService">

    <adapters>
        <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="true" />
        <adapter-definition id="jms" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter"/>
        <adapter-definition id="feed" class="packagename.className"/>
    </adapters>
    <destination id="feed">
        <properties>
            <network>
                <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
            </network>
            <server>
                <max-cache-size>1000</max-cache-size>
                <message-time-to-live>0</message-time-to-live>
                <durable>false</durable>
            </server>
        </properties>
        <channels>
            <channel ref="my-rtmp"/>
        </channels>
    </destination>
</service>
```

And this is my AS file:

```
import mx.messaging.Consumer;
import mx.messaging.events.MessageEvent;
import mx.messaging.events.MessageFaultEvent;
import mx.messaging.messages.IMessage;

private var listner: Consumer;

// functio to handle the creationComplete event:
public function ccHandler(): void {

    listner = new Consumer();
    listner.addEventListener(MessageEvent.MESSAGE, onReceiveMessageFromServer);
    listner.addEventListener(MessageFaultEvent.FAULT, onFailedReceiveMessageFromServer);
}

// receive message handler:
private function onReceiveMessageFromServer(message: IMessage): void {

    lblMessageReceivedFromServer.text = message.body.toString();
}

// fault message handler:
private function onFailedReceiveMessageFromServer(message: IMessage): void {

    lblMessageReceivedFromServer.text = "Error when receiving message from 'feed'";
}
```

Java class (destination) to send data at regular intervals:

```
import flex.messaging.MessageBroker;
import flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage;
import flex.messaging.messages.Message;
import flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter;
import flex.messaging.util.UUIDUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author adeshpande
 */
public class ServerPushManager extends ServiceAdapter {

    private volatile boolean running;

    public static void sendMessageToClients() {

        // random no. to send to client:
        double dNumber = 0;

        // set the message broker 
        final MessageBroker msgBroker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);

        // set the UUID:
        final String clientId = UUIDUtils.createUUID(false);

        // create the message to send and set parameters
        final AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
        msg.setDestination("feed");
        msg.setClientId(clientId);
        msg.setMessageId((UUIDUtils.createUUID(false)));
        msg.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dNumber = Math.random()*100;
        msg.setBody(dNumber);
        System.out.println("\n---- Message to send: " +dNumber +" ----\n");

        // send the message into the message routing system:
        msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);
    }

    /*
    private void sendMessageToClients(Message msg) {

        ((MessageService) getDestination().getService()).pushMessageToClients(msg, false);
    }
    */


    @Override                  // flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter ---> start()
    public void start(){

        super.start();
        Thread messageSender = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){

                running = true;
                while(running){

                    sendMessageToClients();
                    secondsToSleep(3);
                }
            }
        };
        messageSender.start();        
    }


    @Override                   // flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter ---> stop()
    public void stop(){

        super.stop();
        running = false;
    }



    @Override
    public Object invoke(Message message) {

        if (message.getBody().equals("stop")) {

            running = false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void secondsToSleep(int seconds) {

        try{

            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

            System.out.println("TestServiceAdapter Interrupted while sending messages");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you found solution for LoginCommandSettings.setMatch method?

Comment: Not yet, still trying somethings but started working on some other things... If u have some thing to share, please do so...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the RTMP and RTMPT protocols are only available in LiveCycle Data Services (LCDS), not BlazeDS, which explains the errors.

Comment: In other words, you must use the AMF protocol

Comment: It's RTMPT that is not available

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is something wrong with your blaze setup. Finding the problem might be difficult. Instead, try to work of a clean slate of BlazeDS. Here's a simple 2 minute setup you can try:

- Install blazeDS on tomcat
- Make a copy of webapps/blazeds, and rename the copy to whatever you called your application
- Now add all the java classes you coded to the webapps/my-application/WEB-INF/classes folder
- Configure WEB-INF/flex/remoting-config and services-config.xml files

This way you will be sure that all the dependent libs, classes and config files are included in your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  The web-app is already existing under tomcat/webapps/my-application. It also has the WEB-INF/ folder, under which following sub-folders exist:  classes, flex, jsp, lib, sessions, and web.xml.  Thing is that this setup was working fine before I started experimenting with server-push. As soon as I added the new **<destination>** to my messaging-config and started tomcat, it began throwing these errors. Any guesses what would be missing? And why is it calling a method that does not exist? [**LoginCommandSettings.setMatch();**]

Comment: If it is working fine without the new destination, then it means that there is a problem with your new destination. Could it be that your destination is perhaps calling a service that requires the function that doesn't exist? As far as I know AMF is not performing login commands.

Comment: I am trying to use RTMP channel: <channel-definition id="my-rtmp" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
            <endpoint url="rtmp://{server.name}:2038" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.RTMPEndpoint"/>
            <properties>
                <idle-timeout-minutes>20</idle-timeout-minutes>
            </properties>
        </channel-definition>

Comment: I have added messaging-config.xml to my question, along with the Actionscript file that is trying to collect data... Hope this helps